# Query on definition used for inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, definition, inner-products

I'm reading "Symmetric Bilinear Forms" by Milnor. In it he makes the following definition.

"A symmetric inner product space $S$ over the ring $R$ is said to be *split* if there exists a submodule $N\subset S$ such that $N$ is a direct summand of $S$, and such that $N$ is precisely equal to its orthogonal complement $N^{\bot}$."

Is this correct, "precisely equal to its orthogonal complement"? seems off. Maybe I just don't understand it. He also mentions "this concept is due to Knebusch, who uses the term "metabolic" in place of our split".

Would be great if anyone could clear this up or point me to another reference.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: How can something be its own complement? usually orthogonal complements have empty intersection I thought?

Comment: Consider the symmetric product $Q((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=x_1x_2-y_1y_2$. What is the orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by $(1,1)$?

Comment: The subspace spanned by (1,1)?